# General Keyboarding question

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I am new to "keyboard shortcuts".  In the formula (Alt+Ctrl+Num-)what is the meaning/location on the keyboard of Num-?

Answer (score 3):

Num- is the minus button on the [Numpad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numpad) (see picture in link)

Answer (score 1):

The minus (`-`) key on the numeric keypad. Or, in other words, the key on the upper right of your keyboard.